# Why several of isomers of octane such as 2,3-dimethylhexane and 2,4-dimethylhexane doesn't have a value for melting point from any databases?

Tags: periodic-trends, isomers

This is a very rough data (as shown below) I have collected from CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics 93rd edition in black and ChemSpider in blue. As you can see, I am not quite done, but I was wondering why several of the isomers of octane such as 2,3-dimethylhexane and 2,4-dimethylhexane doesn't have a value for melting point from both databases? (I have tried searching up the melting point for each on a reliable database and have come up with no value given. Wikipedia *does* give a melting point, but I am very cautious about using that data as it does not a source to prove it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to include more than one (secondary) reference and to widen the querry -- if there is access -- to general chemistry data bases like Chemical Abstracts (by the American Chemical Society), or Reaxys (by Elsevier), and Springer Materials, too.

In addition, do not stick to *one* chemical name, and equally include in your querry unique identifiers like the CAS registry number -- applicable regardless how the organic nomenclature is applied (including databases in other languages) -- rather than one chemical name.  By doing so, you may rapidly find addtional data, for example among chemical suppliers like Sigma-Aldrich, that lists 2,3,4-trimethylpentane (CAS-RN 565-75-3) in its catalog with a melting point of −110 °C and a boiling point of 113-114 °C.

Beside electronic ressources, consider additional ones available in print, like volumes in Landolt-Bornstein dedicated to condensed matter (now included in Springer Materials).